# difference between earley and lalr parser in lark?

Tags: parsing, lark-parser

I have a simple grammar, which parse key-value pairs section by section.

```
k1:1
k2:x

k3:3
k4:4
```

The grammar I have for it is:

```
start:  section (_sep section)*
_sep: _NEWLINE _NEWLINE+
section: item (_NEWLINE item)*
item: NAME ":" VALUE

_NEWLINE: /\r?\n[\t ]*/
VALUE: /\w+/
NAME: /\w+/
```

However, the grammar works when using the earley parser, but not using lalr parser.

with the following code:

```
from lark import Lark
import logging
from pathlib import Path
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

my_grammar = Path("my_grammar.lark").read_text()
print(my_grammar)
early = Lark(my_grammar, debug=True)

print(my_grammar)
lalr = Lark(my_grammar, parser='lalr', debug=True)

text = """
k1:1
k2:x

k3:3
k4:4
"""
print(text.strip())
print(early.parse(text.strip()).pretty())
print(lalr.parse(text.strip()).pretty())
```

the earley parser give me the valid result.

```
start
  section
    item
      k1
      1
    item
      k2
      x
  section
    item
      k3
      3
    item
      k4
      4
```

but lalr parser did not

```
lark.exceptions.UnexpectedCharacters: No terminal defined for '
' at line 3 col 1


^

Expecting: {'NAME'}
```

PS: the problem is with the _NEWLINE.

Lark-parser grammar config the lexer and parser in on grammar file. In my grammar above, a line will be tokenized as _NEWLINE. Multiple new line will be tokenized as _NEWLINE.. _NEWLINE. It confuse the parser.

change `_sep` to `/\r?\n[\t ]*(\r?\n[\t ]*)/`. multiple line will be tokenized as one token. and lalr(1) parser can work on it smoothly.

while I get it working. still curious about how early parser got it right.